# Can a powerful machine improve performance of DELETE?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.7 and trying to delete 100 million rows from an Innodb table by primary key.

The table is built in a RDS and I execute the delete query via SQLYOG on my personal PC.

In my view, no matter which client connect to the RDS, it only send the delete query to RDS and then the RDS run it and will not use the resources from client. However, I was told that if I connect to the RDS and execute the delete query on a powerful server, it will significantly accelerate the speed.

Is this true? Could anyone explain it please?

Comment: I think the mean if you up the machine the RDS is running on. e.g. `db.t3.micro` is going to be slower than `db.t3.2xlarge`

Comment: Please don't laugh have you turned auto commit off as well?

Comment: Hi @bibble235  Thanks for your reply. I am using transaction to execute the `delete` query. I think it will not use auto commit but feel free to correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: In C++ I set this on the connection e.g. mysql_autocommit(m_MYSQLInstance.get(), false); You can do this on AWS looking at [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-3-parameters-related-to-security-operational-manageability-and-connectivity-timeout/)

Comment: I believe that if you first drop all other indexes (except PK), delete the rows and then recreate the indexes (if any) - it will speed up the process. Also, if you have triggers on the table - think about whether you can safely disable them. If the number of rows that will remain undeleted is MUCH smaller than the amount of those to be deleted - it may be more efficient to first copy these "remaining rows" into a temp table, truncate the original, then copy temp rows back into original table.

Comment: If you are deleting _all_ of the rows in the table, consider using `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

The beefiness of the server is not likely to matter.

A big delete needs to

- Locate the rows to delete
- Lock the rows -- to keep others from making a mess
- Save a copy of each row that is being deleted (in case of crash/rollback)
- Update indexes (some of this is delayed until after the `DELETE` completes)
- Clean up the deleted rows (at `COMMIT` time)

Performance issues:

- MySQL does most of this in a single CPU -- so, more cores won't help
- CPU speed is not the gating factor -- anyway, today's CPUs are only slightly faster than decade-old cpus.
- Disk speed matters -- but most machines use SSDs today
- Cloud services "provision" IOPs.  This *can* matter.  (But let's try to diminish the number of IOPs *needed*.)
- Disk size does not matter -- well, it does matter if you fill up disk with the old copies of the rows.

That is, a more powerful server won't help much.

What *can* help is to answer these questions:

- If most of the rows are to be deleted, there is a much faster way
- If the rows being deleted are "old" rows, plan ahead with `PARTITIONing`.  (This is viable *only* if you can replace `DELETE` with `DROP PARTITION`.)
- If the above fail, are you deleting in batches?  (A batch of about 1000 rows is nearly optimal.  It will be several times as fast as one-at-a-time.  And going above 1000 won't buy much, if any, performance.)

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: Just a minor addition which applies to RDS only: provisioned disk size does matter because it directly affects IOPS, unless provisioned IOPS are used.

Comment: @Cascader - Point made.  Cloud providers artificially slow down I/O.  Some of my suggestions will help in this area.